# Finding a ribbon graph for a mapping class group action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, surgery-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

Turaev defines TQFT $(T, \tau)$ in his book "Quantum invariants of knots and 3-manifolds". He uses it to define an action of a mapping class group of a d-surface $\Sigma$.

This action $\epsilon$ is defined as follows.

1. Consider the cylinder $\Sigma \times [0, 1]$. The top and bottom parametrizations are the identity and $g$ respectively, where $g$ is an element of a mapping class group of $\Sigma$. Denote this cobordism by $M(g)$.
2. Define an action of $g$ by $\epsilon(g)=\tau(M(g))$.

To calculate $\tau(M(g))$, we first need to find a special ribbon graph which presents $M(g)$.

**Question**

Is there any algorthm to find such a special ribbon graph if we are given an element $g$ of a mapping class group?

More generally, is there any way to find a special ribbon graph that presents a given cobordism?

Could you give me references?

Comment: Dear Link S. It seems that you are the same person as "Link" and "Knot". Could you consolidate your MO accounts? Also, you should explain how ribbon graphs relate to $M(g)$, since not everybody is as familiar with Turaev's book as you are. 

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87567/a-special-ribbon-graph-presents-a-cylinder

Comment: @Misha, I will register.
@ Daniel, it is not the same question as in your link. Or do you mean I need to study kno theory first as this is the answer to that question? 